# Could not write JSON: Unable to find com.demo.model.Control with id 0;

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I spent all day in order to solve this issue, however I still did not get the reason of it because my projet and controle table are not empty and why the JPA look for a Controle with  id=0?:

> WARN 5764 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Unable to find com.demo.model.Controle with id 0; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unable to find com.demo.model.Controle with id 0 (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.demo.model.Projet["Controle"]->com.demo.model.Control$HibernateProxy$aqtpKvMx["nomControle"])]

here is my two models:

**Projet entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="projets")
public class Projet implements Serializable{
//other properties
//.....
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    @JoinColumn(name="id_controle")
    private Controle controle;
//....
//other getters and sitters
    public Controle getControle() {
        return Controle;
    }

    public void setControle(Controle controle) {
        this.Controle = controle;
    }
}
```

** Control entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="controle")
public class Controle implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7906212173191059200L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id_controle", nullable=false)
    private int  idControle;

    @Column(name="nom_controle", nullable = true)
    private String nomControle;

    @Column(name="tel_controle", nullable = true)
    private String telControle;

    @Column(name="email_controle", nullable = true)
    private String emailControle;

    @Column(name="address_controle", nullable = true)
    private String addressControle;

    protected Controle() {
    }

    public Controle(String nom, String tel, String email, String address) {
        super();
        this.nomControle = nom;
        this.telControle = tel;
        this.emailControle= email;
        this.addressControle = address;
    }

//other getters and sitters
public String getNomControle() {
        return nomControle;
    }

    public void setNomControle(String nomControle) {
        this.nomControle = nomControle;
    }
```

Im getting this error when I try to fetch all the projects through the `getAllProjet()` method of the `JpaRepository`.

**ProjetController:** this method was working before and now it triggered the error:

```
@GetMapping("/projets")
    public List<Projet> getAllProjet(){
        List<Projet> p = projetRepository.findAll();
        Collections.reverse(p);
        return p;
    }
```

Also im getting this error in the client side:

> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/projets", ok: false, …}

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The list contains a Projet, which is supposed to be associated with the Controle with ID 0, but this controle doesn't exist. So your data in the database seems to be in an incoherent state (there should be a foreign key constraint making it impossible for a projet to have a reference to an unexisting Controle). Note that the code you posted can't compile...

Comment: @JBNizet well i have foreign key relation between Projet and Controle... before everything was working well thats why i dont get the reason.
Please explain me more why this code can't compile? Thank you

Comment: Because a class named BureauxControle has a constructor named Controle, because you refer to a variable named controle using Controle, etc.

Comment: Yes you right, it's only a mistake, I will correct it

Comment: My Code is compiling, however this error manifest each time i try to list all projects, why getAllProjet() asks for a controle with id=0 which doesn't exist?

Comment: Most probably because, as the message and my comment says, one of the Project has a reference to a controle with ID 0, i.e. one of the rows of the projet table has an id_controle with value 0.

Comment: Thank you ... I checked my projet rows .... and you right about it.

Comment: The reason of this issue is that my table has empty column of foreign key ... I have another question related to this issue, how to overcome this in order to display data even it is empty???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The origin of this issue was the add of a new column `"controle"` to my table `"projet"` with a foreign key to `"controle"` table. Therefore, the values of rows of that column are empty.

To overcome the

> `"HttpMessageNotWritableException"` issue - when I try to display the empty value-

and even the

> `"HttpMessageNotReadableException"` issue -when I try to add a new Object with empty value in the foreign key-

I added this condition in the frontend part that verifies the inserted value:

```
if (this.projetForm.controls.controle.value === '') {
      formValue['controle']=null;
    }
```

This technique helped me to solve the issue, I hope this solution will help someone facing the same  error.